# Some json-rpc requests are not served by a possibly unsynced full node on localhost

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, synchronization, leveldb, full-node

I want to make some JSON RPC calls to my rinkeby node, which I have set up via:

```
$ geth --rinkeby --http --http.api personal,eth,net,web3 --cache=4096 --http.port 3337
```

I seem to have problems retrieving information about the network via RPC calls. For example, I use the ethers-js library to inquire about the network and some random account with ETH, that I found:

```js
const ethers = require('ethers')
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('http://localhost:3337')
provider.getNetwork()
        .then(console.log)
        .catch(console.log)
provider.getBalance('0x1CBFf6551B8713296b0604705B1a3B76D238Ae14')
        .then(console.log)
        .catch(console.log)
```

The response will be `{name: 'rinkeby', chainId: 4, ...}` for the network, so all correct here. But `BigNumber { _hex: '0x00', _isBigNumber: true }`, i.e. zero for that account. I also checked with my test account with rinkeby-ETH and got zero.

On the console these calls produce only the `eth_chainId` call:

```bash
WARN [12-26|02:17:51.167] Served eth_chainId                       conn=127.0.0.1:60186 reqid=42 duration="24.634µs" err="chain not synced beyond EIP-155 replay-protection fork block"
WARN [12-26|02:17:51.175] Served eth_chainId                       conn=127.0.0.1:60190 reqid=44 duration="25.471µs" err="chain not synced beyond EIP-155 replay-protection fork block"
```

Otherwise I always get the following appearing every couple of seconds:

```
WARN [12-26|02:22:11.966] Database compacting, degraded performance database=/home/myname/.ethereum/rinkeby/geth/chaindata
WARN [12-26|02:23:11.974] Database compacting, degraded performance database=/home/myname/.ethereum/rinkeby/geth/chaindata
```

In the directory `/home/myname/.ethereum/rinkeby/geth/chaindata` I see a ton of leveldb files, the latest one currently downloading is `409835.ldb`. Is this the block-number? In which case I am quite far off, since the block number of rinkeby at the time of writing is 9879139. On the other hand the directory has a size of 79.1GB, so to me it sounds quite large and I remember that I ran the `--syncmode 'snap'` today for a few hours where a percentage of synced data was moving towards and finally reaching 100%.

Why can I not inquire about an account balance? Can I use json-rpc calls even if the db is not fully synced?

Answer (score 1):

The current account balance data is not stored in the blockchain itself, but is determined based on the execution of transactions on a specific node. Therefore, you will find out the current balance only after the node is fully synchronized, when all transactions related to the desired account are "rolled".

Comment: Thanks Mad. How do I know which percentage of the data I have already synchronized. Could I query geth somehow or get some cues from the progression of files in  the chaindata folder?

Comment: You could see what you are currently state chain if you are using the eth.syncing command. It will return your current block and the highest block number in rinkeby.